# Footer do not stays at one place, wrapper dissapear

Tags: html, css, footer, wrapper

I know that this question been answered for a million times, but i just cant make it work! I want my footer to stay at the bottom of the page, but it keeps on making strange things.

That is my html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>Chollerton Tearooms</title>


    <style>
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="logo">

</div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Find out more</a></li>
          <li><a href="#offer">Offer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
          <li><a href="#admin">Admin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#wireframe">Wireframe</a></li>
         </ul>

        <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="offer">
            <h1>Chollerton Tearooms</h1> 
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
            <p>Hello, this is my first web page at University.</p>
        <br> <br>
        </div>
       <footer>

            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            <p>Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer.Footer. </p>
            </footer>
            </div>
     </body>
        </html>
```

and that is css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("ba1.jpg");
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
    }

.logo {
    background: url(nl.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 283px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;


    }


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #6fb9d6;
    width: 960px;
    text-align:center;
    }

li {
    display:inline-block;
    }

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

/* Change the link color to #d05568 (pink) on hover */
li  a:hover {
    background-color: #d05568;
    }

/* Change the nav element color when active */  
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    }

h1 {text-align: center;}
p {text-align: center;}

*{ 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    } 

.wrapper{ 
        background: url(bwflowerstop.png) no-repeat top;
        background-color: #fff;
        width:960px; 
        margin:0 auto; 
        text-align:left; 
    }


footer {

    background: url(bwflowersbottom.png) no-repeat bottom;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Idealy i would like web site to look like first picture, and now it looks like second [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeyHH.jpg)

but when i, for example, add this bit:

```
.offer{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 20px;}
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcv87.jpg)

Any advises? :(
Thank you!

Comment: it looks fine to me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqugjr8/)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/85h4z2w3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second div with id="container" inside the wrapper and include into it the  and the . Put the container a float: left css to!

Comment: very short answer lease improve it and use the code block.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<div class="MotherDiv" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
your content 
</div
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp